# How can i set a drop down's user seeing value dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

How can i set a drop down's user seeing value dynamically, like we are setting for textbox as shown below..,

```
document.getElementById('address').value=addressVal;
```

Iam a starter in JS, help me.

Comment: You do it the same way, just set the value. http://jsbin.com/awaxol/1/edit

Comment: Try this: `document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex = someIndex;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following markup:

```
<select id="dd">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Lemon</option>
</select>
```

You can do this in two ways:

**I. Setting `value`:**

```
document.getElementById('dd').value = 'Banana';
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hdvfN/)

---

**II. Setting `selectedIndex`:**

```
document.getElementById('dd').selectedIndex = 2;
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hdvfN/1/)

---

### NOTE

Method II (`selectedIndex`) is more safe, if you have `value` attribute
in your `option` tags:

```
<select id="dd">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Orange</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Lemon</option>
</select>
```

The method I, will select the second option (`Orange`) as it's value is `Banana` ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdvfN/2/)).

But the method II, will still select the third option (`Banana`) as it's index is 2.